# siginfo_t si_pid =0?

Tags: linux, signals

I'm using a signal handler with `siginfo_t` field for gathering some informations, if the field `si_pid` is `0` it means that the sender of the signal is the same who receives it? If that's the case is equal to `raise(int signum)` right?

Example: Process 1 sends SIGALRM, Process 1 signal handler's output relative to `si_pid` equals 0, this means that it's like Process1 is doing `raise(SIGALRM)`?

This is the situation:

N processes install `SIGARLM`  and every `(BIRTH_DEATH/2)` second i want them to send ONLY TO THEMSELVES (like if it was a `raise(SIGARLM)`) an alarm, they have the same pgrp, since si->si_pid is 0 i dont understand if all these processes get the signals of others or not, should i use some `masks` on the signal?

code of installation for SIGALRM (same for all processes):

```
sa_target.sa_sigaction = &a_target_reduce;
sa_target.sa_flags = SA_NODEFER | SA_RESTART | SA_SIGINFO;   
sigemptyset(&my_mask_target);      
sa_target.sa_mask = my_mask_target;
sigaction(SIGALRM, &sa_target, NULL);

alarm(BIRTH_DEATH/2);
```

handling code (i know `printf` it's not fine here):

```
void a_target_reduce(int signal, siginfo_t *si, void *context) {
    printf("I'm %d received signal from %d real id %d\n", getpid(), si->si_pid, si->si_uid);
    counter_reduce++;
    alarm(BIRTH_DEATH/2);   
}
```

Comment: I can't see any mentions of `si_pid` being zero, at least not in the [`sigaction` man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html). What situation do you get that in?

Comment: @ilkkachu edited hope it's clear the situation

Comment: Try looking at `si->si_code` as well.  If it's `SI_KERNEL`, the `si_pid` field as far as I can tell won't matter. You'll see SI_KERNEL with timers or the user sending SIGINT by typing ^C, for example. If si_code is `SI_USER`, `si_pid` should show the pid/tid who sent the signal with `kill` or `raise`. I'm less clear on your other questions. `alarm()` is only going to send a signal to a single process, not a set of related processes. If you want to use signals for IPC, the SIGUSR1 and SIGUSR2 signals, sent with `kill()`,  are probably better choices than the signals that have other uses.

Comment: @Mark Plotnick alarm() sends a signal only to one process, does that mean that if I have installed the handler  for him  in all processes only the first to catch it will see  it?

Comment: No. alarm() sends a signal to the same process in which it was called, and that's it. If you call `fork` after you call `alarm`, the alarm is cancelled in the child.

Comment: "Alarm() sends signal only to process in which it was called". I'm in OSX Unix. Marks' statement seems to be false here. I have several processes (two for simplicity, #1 and #2) using setitimer to run each process. So long as the interval time in each process is the same, both run OK and remain synchronous. But, as soon as the interval time of one process (#1) is changed (by a gui slider) #1 now runs at the new speed but process #2 is drastically slowed - perhaps 10 times slower than #1.

Comment: So there MUST BE an interaction between the SIGALRM in process #1 and the setitimer function and SIGALRM signal_handler in process #2 -- and presumably vice-versa.